# Can we directly install ROS Kinetic packages on PC running Ubuntu 16.04 without installing ROS Kinetic on that PC?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, packages, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to the ROS and Ubuntu world.While I was trying to install ROS Kinetic on PC running Ubuntu 16.04 a new question arose to my mind that "**whether it is always necessary to install first the ROS Kinetic on the PC running Ubuntu 16.04 or we can directly install ROS Kinetic packages like TurtleSim,Catkin,etc. on the PC using the command 'sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-[PACKAGE_NAME]' without installing the ROS on PC(which will include some of the packages already in it)."**

And if it is possible to directly install packages on the PC running Ubuntu without completely installing ROS on PC,will we be able to used all the commands of the ROS like roscore,rosrun,rospack,source the environment,catkin,etc. in that PC.

Link:- http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

Any help in these question will be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255107/can-we-directly-install-ros-kinetic-packages-on-pc-running-ubuntu-16.04-without-installing-ros-kinetic-on-that-pc-?/) by [a443](https://answers.ros.org/users/29219/a443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

You have install first ROS in your computer that the  [link](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) and then you could install the package.

---

Originally posted by [CarlosBarreiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/28260/carlosbarreiro/) with karma: 36 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1